# Mail Exception in Production

Tags: email, exception, laravel-5, production-environment

I am working on a project in Laravel. I need to send some emails to the users. When I am testing the project in local, the emails are sending and receiving to the appropriate users. But when I am testing it in the production, the emails not sending. At that time I got an error which is #1. Please, Help me to resolve this issue.

1. Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com

The setup which I did in the env file is

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=*******@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=****************@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=NAME
```

Comment: Which hosting company domain you are using???

Comment: Linux Hosting (cPanel)

Comment: Can you tell me exact name of company

Comment: GoDaddy - Linux Hosting (cPanel)

Answer (score 0):

Some hosting companies tend you to use their mailing protocols.

In GoDaddy you have to configure .env according to cPanel->Email Wizard->Configure Mail Client

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the information. Will you please give me more details to do that

Comment: MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=ap*.s******e.y***r.*t*****h***s@pe****rb****hou****.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=***********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=app.scribble.your.thoughts@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Scribble"

Comment: I changed my env file like this, but still i got the error - Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com

Comment: Please set MAIL_HOST according to Incoming Server or Outgoing Server from Recommended Section

Comment: Thank you. Now the success message is coming, but the mail not receiving. @Faiez

Comment: Well try different port and encryption methods. Now it is dependent on your connection with your mail company.

Comment: Although the connection is established by server, what you have asked. Next is your personal info and it all depends on mailing company.

Comment: Sir if server is sending mail then, please accept the answer.

Next is your mail company setting to receive mails. Check these links for more info
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/j5mtk2YDODI/_j1Vm6OUAgAJ

https://help.hover.com/hc/en-us/articles/217282007-I-can-send-email-but-I-can-t-receive

Comment: When you open this location cPanel->Email Wizard->Configure Mail Client have you given same mail which you are using now.

Comment: Yes. I created a new one, then I click the mail configuration. From there I got the details of username, host, etc.

Comment: Yes, now fill env according to that info and check the mail you have given in "Configure Mail Client"

Comment: I already fill the env file according to the information from Configure Mail Client. But the mail which sends from my app is not delivering

Comment: It is must that you want to use gmail